# "Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateCineflixPrimeMiviTv does not exist."

Tags: validation

why iam getting this error while setuping my webiste installation. Like this on top left panel - BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateCineflixPrimeMiviTv does not exist.

` }

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic calls to class methods.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    $rule = Str::snake(substr($method, 8));

    if (isset($this->extensions[$rule])) {
        return $this->callExtension($rule, $parameters);
    }

    throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
        'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    ));
}
```

}`